# Расчет суммы денег

Tags: c++

Дано задание под номером 7. Первые два года рассчитывает правильно, а вот на 10 год получается такой ответ = 10998.4 
В чем моя ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int year;
   double procent, capital, begin;
   cout << "Enter the initial contribution: ";
   cin >> begin;
   cout << "Enter the number of year: ";
   cin >> year;
   cout << "Enter the interest rate: ";
   cin >> procent;
   for (int i = 0; i < year; i++)
   {
       begin = (i * 165) + begin;
       capital = begin + (begin * (procent * 0.01));
   }
   cout << "In " << year << " you will receive " << capital << " dollars" << 
   endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в алгоритме, т.е. он изначально неверен:

```
capital = begin
for(int i = 0; i < years; i++){
    capital += capital * (procent / 100 )
}
cout << "In " << year << " you will receive " << capital << " dollars" << endl;
```

Т.е. по факту вам нужно удалить первую строчку в цикле